# Using selenium to paginate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pagination

I am trying to use selenium to paginate the next button. I am testing this on a small scale hoping to eventually do hundreads of pages. So far I can make it go through all the pages on the small scale website, but it does not break when the next page buttom is disabled. My code is below any help would be appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Provide the path to the downloaded Chrome WebDriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.usgbc.org/projects/?Country=%5B%22United+States%22%5D&Rating+System=%5B%22New+Construction%22%5D&Rating+Version=%5B%22v2009%22%5D&Certification=%5B%22Platinum%22%5D&State=%5B%22Texas%22%5D")
# check this is the right website
# print(driver.title)


while True:
    # Perform your desired actions on each page here

    # Check if the next button is disabled
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/section/div/div/div[3]/a[4]')))
    if next_button.get_attribute('aria-disabled') == 'true':
        break  # Exit the loop if the next button is disabled

    # Click the next button to navigate to the next page
    next_button.click()

driver.quit()
```

I tried changing the get_attribute to different items, but I cannot seem to find the right format. The most confusing thing for me is knowing which XPATH to use to check if the next button is present.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You said, "but it does not break when the next page button is disabled". Does that you mean *want* it to break? Please [edit] your question to include the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use stable locators instead of indexed ones for Next button like below

You can check if next button is disabled  like below then break out of loop

```
next_button.get_attribute('Disabled')
```

Full code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Provide the path to the downloaded Chrome WebDriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.usgbc.org/projects/?Country=%5B%22United+States%22%5D&Rating+System=%5B%22New+Construction%22%5D&Rating+Version=%5B%22v2009%22%5D&Certification=%5B%22Platinum%22%5D&State=%5B%22Texas%22%5D")
# check this is the right website
# print(driver.title)


while True:
    # Perform your desired actions on each page here
    # Add some wait here for next page load
    # Check if the next button is disabled
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="result-grid"]//a[text()="Next"]')))
    if next_button.get_attribute('Disabled'):
        break  # Exit the loop if the next button is disabled
    else:
        # Click the next button to navigate to the next page
        next_button.click()

driver.quit()
```